# I'm getting a value in my jmeter script while login to the application through login.microsoft which is i19 help me progress to it

Tags: authentication, time, jmeter, request, response

While debugging it a function passes through that values which is

```
timeOnPage((new Date).getTime() - r.performance.timing.loadEventEnd)
```

Help me to approach it in jmeter and also if possible kindly attach any reference

'login': 'username',
'loginfmt': 'username,
'type': 11,
'LoginOptions': 3,
'passwd': 'passowrd',
'ps': 2,
'PPSX': 'P',
'NewUser': 1,
'fspost': 0,
'i21': 0,
'CookieDisclosure': 0,
'IsFidoSupported': 1,
'i2': 1,
'i17': 0,
'i18': '__ConvergedLoginPaginatedStrings|1,__OldConvergedLogin_PCore|1,__OldConvergedLogin_PAlt|1,',
'i19': 18430,
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if you're absolutely sure that you need to pass the current timestamp to the `i19` [input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) you can use [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) which returns the current timestamp in milliseconds since the beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)